# Get id from database when create tag in Select2

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a select2 tagging control. When tag not exists, user can create tag. This tags are saved in database, but the problem is that I don't know how to set tag id returned for ajax success.

```
$tags.select2({
    placeholder: '- Select -',
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    createTag: function (params) {
        if (params.term.trim() === '') {
            return null;
        }
        return {
            id: '', //How to get id here???
            text: params.term.toLowerCase(),
            newTag: true // add additional parameters
        }
    },
    //Ajax to get tags here ommited
});

$tags.on('select2:select', function (e) {
    if (e.params.data.newTag) {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlAddTag,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { tag: e.params.data.text.toLowerCase() },
            success: function (response) {
                 e.params.data.id = response.id;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In the ajax response I'm setting the id with which tag was stored in database, but I don't know how to pass to 'createTag' function.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issue and I solved in the following way, I don't expect this adapts 100% to your case but it might give you an idea.

My flow works in this way:

- in the createTag, I just create some random id which will be sent to
  the API
- the API will ignore this id and just creates a new record using the
  text from the select2 component
- the API returns the new id (and text) in the response
- in the callback you update the tags on select2 with the new ID you
  just got

So for instance in your case:

```
createTag: function(params) {
  if (params.term.trim() === '') {
      return null;
  }
  return {
      id: 'new_attribute',
      isNew: true,
      text: params.term
  };
}
```

In the server callback I search through the tags in the control and update its ID with the one I get from the server:

```
$('<option/>').val(response.id).html(response.text).appendTo($tags); //create a new option with id + text returned by the server
var tags = $tags.val(); //get current values
var index = tags.indexOf('new_attribute'); //look for new_attribute
if (index !== -1) {
    tags[index] = response.id; //replace 'new_attribute' with id got from the server
}
$tags.val(tags).trigger('change'); //update select2
```

Comment: I think that there must be a different way to accomplish this with a callback, but in the meantime, I'm gonna use this hack, thank you Dario